# Test panel returns json in v3 API format, while v2 is preferable

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Example of current response using test panel:

```
{
  "query": "incident 2",
  "prediction": {
    "normalizedQuery": "incident 2",
    "topIntent": "INCIDENT_DETAILS",
    "intents": {
      "INCIDENT_DETAILS": {
        "score": 0.972139537
      }
    },
    "entities": {
      "INCIDENT_NUMBER": [
        "2"
      ],
      "$instance": {
        "INCIDENT_NUMBER": [
          {
            "type": "INCIDENT_NUMBER",
            "text": "2",
            "startIndex": 9,
            "length": 1,
            "score": 0.989707232,
            "modelTypeId": 1,
            "modelType": "Entity Extractor",
            "recognitionSources": [
              "model"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What it was before v3:

```
{
  "query": "incident 2",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "INCIDENT_DETAILS",
    "score": 0.972139537
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "2",
      "type": "INCIDENT_NUMBER",
      "startIndex": 9,
      "endIndex": 9,
      "score": 0.989707232
    }
  ]
}
```

Have I missed how to setup what API version should be used for test panel? Obviously it's really inconvenient if we don't have such option.

Comment: Are you using www.luis.ai or preview.luis.ai?

Comment: @DFBerry Hi, just have double checked and confirm it's https://www.luis.ai/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ability to switch between API versions within the luis.ai site is not available. It is a feature being considered however there is no ETA, at this time.

Hope of help!